# Wait before firing a function to execute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How can I set a delayed trigger in JavaScript to execute a function after a specified amount of time?

My program will wait for 5 seconds to execute `demo();` and if it fails to start demo within 5 seconds I need to execute `sample()` automatically.

Is this possible to do in JavaScript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can invoke functions after a period of time with setTimeout

```
setTimeout(demo, 5000);
```

I'm not sure that I get the "*if it is fail to start demo with in 5 seconds*" part of your question, because the above code *will* execute demo() in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at:

- **[setInterval](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm)**
- **[setTimeout](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm)**
- **[clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)**

**Example:**

```
setTimeout(function(){your code here}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script language="javascript">
function sample() {
  alert('sample here');
}
function demo() {
  alert('demo here');
}
setTimeout("sample()", 5000);
</script>

<input type=button onclick="demo();">
```

Comment: very good explanation!thank you so much.But, actually your script will involk both function with the interval of 5 seconds.actually i need only one function at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)** for a pause in javascript.

```
setTimeout(function(){callSample();}, 5000);
```

then set a ***global variable*** inside `demo()` so that you can identify whether `demo()` has been called or not and then in

```
function callSample()
{
    if (variable set)
    {
        sample();
    }
}
```